# How set inline div with background image and text?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="cn_header">
    <div class="print"></div>
    example
</div>​

.cn_header{
    background: #C2E1FF;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.print{
    background: url(http://mcgrefer.com/images/search.png);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Luntegg/2SCvf/1/

How set inline div with background image and text?

Comment: Ok, now you have three different working ways to do that. Shef comment should be an answer too...

Comment: I don't need 'float'

ahhaha, I don't know, how say in english 'BOOBOOBOO'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `vertical-align:middle;` on the `.print`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28JT2/)**

Comment: I also think he should be using that .print div inside another tag for text, like a <p>.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text inside the div:

http://jsfiddle.net/2SCvf/3/

```
<div class="cn_header">
    <div class="print">example</div>
</div>


.cn_header{
    background: #C2E1FF;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 5px;    
}

.print{
    background-image: url(http://mcgrefer.com/images/search.png);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    padding-left: 30px; /* This */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* And This One */
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, in your case is the best i think. It depends on cases, with an higher div (lets say 48px for both divs instead of 24px) vertical-align: middle won't work, while this will: http://jsfiddle.net/2SCvf/6/